# filter api-gateway

Tags: java, spring, микросервисы

Не могу достать значение аргумента.

```
spring:
  cloud:
    gateway:
      routes:
        - id: auth-server-registration
          uri: lb://authorization-service
          predicates:
            - Path=/identity/registration
          filters:
            - name: AuthenticationFilter
              args:
                requiredRole: ROLE_ADMIN

        - id: auth-server-no-filter
          uri: lb://authorization-service
          predicates:
            - Path=/identity/auth
```

Пробую так: `exchange.getAttribute("requiredRole")` - но возвращает `null`.